# Javascript: after a few keypresses gif 'crashes'/pauses on a single frame

Tags: javascript

I have a div that when you press the x key, I am attaching a 'kick' class to. The kick class has a background-image that is a gif. When you first press the x key the gif loads fine. The second time it loads but looks 'buggy', by the third, fourth and so on keypress, the gif is frozen on a single frame.
You can test it out by pressing x a few times in this link:
http://politician-flare-66043.bitballoon.com/test2.html

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #test{
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 640px;
        /*0 40 58*/
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    .image{
        background-image: url('images/sidestepken.png');
        width:9%;
    }
    .kick{
        background-image: url('images/weirdkick.gif');
        width: 100%;
    }
    .first{
        background-image: url('images/sidestepken.png');
        width:9%;
        background-position:0% 0%;
    }
    .second{
        background-image: url('images/sidestepken.png');
        background-position:40% 0%;
        width:9%;
    }
    .third{
        background-image: url('images/sidestepken.png');
        background-position:58% 0%;
        width:9%;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
```

javascript:  (stackoverflow is ignoring my js, but this is inside of a script tag:)

```
document.getElementById('test').className = 'image';
let lefter = 0; 
let uper = 0;
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.code === 'KeyX'){
        console.log('test');
        document.getElementById('test').className = 'kick';
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('test').className = 'image';
        },2000);

    }
    if(e.code === 'ArrowLeft'){
        lefter -= 10;
        changepos();
    }
    if(e.code === 'ArrowRight'){
        lefter += 10;
        changepos();
    }
})
let counter = 0;
function changepos(){
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('test').style.top = uper + 'px';
    document.getElementById('test').style.left = lefter + 'px';
    if(counter === 1){
        console.log('first');
     document.getElementById('test').className = 'first';
    }
    if(counter === 2){ 
        console.log('second');
     document.getElementById('test').className = 'second';
    }   
    if(counter === 3){
        console.log('third');
     document.getElementById('test').className = 'third';
     counter = 0;
    }
}


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` returns a handle to it so that you can clear the timeout after it's over. It may stop the problem

Comment: setTimeout fires once, so who cares about clearing it

Comment: it seems like the GIF is one that isn't a continuous animation ... nothing to do with keystrokes at all --- view the image ... it just stops http://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/a0b9d08e6faffbbdea9760d9d34bbcbb587bfff6/978c2/images/weirdkick.gif

Comment: What? if there's an action required after the setTimeout delay, and the function which sets the timeout runs before the delay, yes, you need to clear it.

Comment: I was trying to point out that the clearing or not of setTimeout is irrelevant to the issue - I guess my English is inelegant

Comment: @JaromandaX you were correct, the gif does not loop, I swapped it with another gif image and the issue did not reoccur. Thank you